# Rendering XML with Stylesheet in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, xml, xslt

I can't figure out how to get a rendered collection (as XML) to include a style sheet line such as:

```
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="example.xsl" ?>
```

[This guy](http://www.markrichman.com/2008/08/09/ruby-on-rails-adding-xsl-processing-instruction-with-to_xml/) says to add a proc as such:

```
proc = Proc.new { |options| options[:builder].instruct!(:xml-stylesheet, type=>'text/xsl', :href=>'something.xsl') }
@foo.to_xml :procs => [proc]
```

But I can't get that to work. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at Nokogiri gem: http://nokogiri.org/Nokogiri/XSLT/Stylesheet.html

```
doc   = Nokogiri::XML(File.read('some_file.xml'))
xslt  = Nokogiri::XSLT(File.read('some_transformer.xslt'))

puts xslt.transform(doc)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [`atom_feed`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/AtomFeedHelper.html#method-i-atom_feed) helper which is included with Rails:

```
atom_feed(instruct: {
    'xml-stylesheet' => {type: 'text/xsl', href: 'styles.xml'}
  }) do |feed|
  feed.title "My Atom Feed"
  # entries...
end
```

Which results in (showing only first 3 lines):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="styles.xml"?>
<feed xml:lang="en-US" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom">
```

Or, if not rendering an `atom_feed`, you can simply use `instruct` inside your builder:

```
xml.instruct! 'xml-stylesheet', href: 'style.xml', type: 'text/xsl'
```